# How to kill the specific child process(exe) in task manager using Java?

Tags: java

Actually I need to run and stop the process(exe) from external machines. I have started the process and kill the exe with following code.It is working fine.

```
 Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String cmd = "taskkill /F /IM \"" + process ;
    System.out.println(cmd);
    rt.exec(cmd);
```

But when I start the exe, it will open another process(exe).When I try to kill the process the parent exe will be killed properly.And I can kill the child process(exe) with the above code.

If I start multiple process and I need to kill one specific process means all the process will be killed.Because the child process names are same.How can I kill one specific child process?

Comment: Can you store the PID when you start the process ?

Comment: I can get the parent process PID ,but I couldn't predict the child process PID.@vincrichaud

Comment: How do you create the child ? If you can't get the PID of the child, or give them different name, you won't be abel to kill a specific child (unless the child kills itself)

Comment: LOL )-  The child will be created by the Parent process. And I know to give the various names for that, but the problem is the child will be created by the parent process only.So is there any option to kill the specific child? @vincrichaud